# Pulling and building io.js from source using a specific version

Tags: node.js, docker, iojs

I'm building a Dockerfile for an io.js project I've been working on, and I'd love to be able to do something similar to the following, but with io.js.

```
## Install Nodejs
RUN wget http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.12.7/node-v0.12.7.tar.gz
RUN tar -xvzf node-v0.12.7.tar.gz
RUN cd /node-v0.12.7/ && ./configure && make && make install clean
```

It seems to me that there should be an equivalent way to do this with io.js distributions.

```
## Install io.js.
RUN wget https://iojs.org/dist/v2.5.0/iojs-v2.5.0-darwin-x64.tar.gz
RUN tar -xvzf iojs-v2.5.0-darwin-x64.tar.gz
# Now run some command that actually installs io.js on the system.
```

The problem seems to be that the io.js "source" that I download from this distribution appears to just contain executables build for different systems, which isn't what I want.

Is there a way I can get the source files for iojs-v2.5.0 so I can go in there and do `./configure --prefix=/usr && make && make check && make install`? It seems it would be way easier if I could do it this way on Docker.

Comment: as a sidenote, for nodejs, instead of your wget and tar, you could just do `ADD http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.12.7/node-v0.12.7.tar.gz` which will do the same. Check the doc for ADD https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#add

Comment: Why is it easier to compile from source than used a binary made for your system?

Comment: @Michael On deeper examination it quickly became clear that it isn't, I'm just curious at this point.

Comment: I will admit for complete immutability you want to compile, but if this is not a shared image, immutability is not necessarily the most convenient practice.

Comment: 100%. That's exactly the way to go for that, but the tradeoff there seemed unfavorable in my case the more I evaluated it.

Answer (score 0):

The url for the source is without arch.

```
https://iojs.org/dist/v2.5.0/iojs-v2.5.0.tar.gz
```

You will need install dependencies to build like make and g++